Application.FileDialog not referenced?
Since my research has led me to belief that my references could have something to do with it ,here my references to my MS Access:

Visual Basic for applications
Microsoft Access 16.0 object library
OLE Automation
Microsoft office 16.0 access database engine object library
Microsoft office 16.0 object library

My problem is I'm trying to merely call up a file dialog as a function with the return being the string path chosen. I start of with
Dim fd as filedialog

Set fd = Application.filedialog(msoFileDialogSave)
With fd

...


Now, the decision with the dim is fine, but the "set" line gives an error saying that the method filedialog for the object "_application" is unsuccessful.
I've looked at similar problems here, but with no success.
I expected to achieve my goals

If it helps, sliding with a mouse on "msoFileDialogsave", I notice that it's empty

You can use this code:
   Dim f As Office.FileDialog
   Dim varItem As String

   Set f = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
   
   With f
      .Title = "My Title"
      .AllowMultiSelect = False                 'or true
      .ButtonName = "Select"                    'give any name
      .Filters.Clear                            'clear filter before set new ones
      .Filters.Add "Excel files", "*.xl*"       'then create new ones
      .Filters.Add "Word files", "*.do*"
      .Filters.Add "Access files", "*.mdb; *.accdb"
      .FilterIndex = 2                          'pre-select one filter
      .InitialFileName = "D:\"                  'start directory

   
   If .Show Then
     ' In case of Multiselect use this code
     For Each varItem In f.SelectedItems
        Debug.Print varItem
     Next varItem
     ' In case of no MultiSelect use this code
     SelectedFileName = f.SelectedItems(1)
   Else
     ' User selected cancel
   EndIf
   End With
End Function

Additional options:

Need reference to "Microsoft Office Object Library"

Your references seem fine, but you must use the correct constants:

As you can see, it is ..SaveAs to use:
